# Android: Emulator customization problems

Tags: android

I have android sdk 21. I'm trying to create a virtual device with api 15 and custom resolution.
The problem is that there is no field where I can set my custom resolution. Is that possible ?. And one more thing, why I cannot change CPU to Intel ?. I downloaded the SDK using android manager.

[image]

Comment: use latest eclipse idt and use there option available for resolution

Comment: r u solved your problem as i said.

Comment: downloading new eclipse....Thanks for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because you are not using the latest Eclipse -> Juno

In my case here is my Eclipse config

[image]

Here are my installs

[image]

And here is what I get in the emulator configuration

[image]

This is on my PC (Windows) but I tested on my MAC Book and it is the exactly the same.